# How to map GROUP_CONCAT with pdo->fetchAll and mode PDO::FETCH_CLASS from string to an array

Tags: php, pdo, magic-function

I was wondering how fetchAll of PDO is actually implemented to get an Idea how to map the result from the database including a GROUP_CONCAT() comma separated list string to an array property.

Having a sql like

`$query = "Select a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) AS referencingNames FROM a JOIN b on (a.id = b.id_a)"`

Will return something like

| id (int) | referencingNames (srting) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mark, Mona, Sam |
| 2 | Jim, Tom, Sara, Mike |
| 3 | ... |

My Object to map to looks like this

```php
class someObject {
  public int $id;
  public array $referencingNames;
}
```

When I call my php code then:

```php
 $pdo = new PDO(....)
 $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();

 $objects = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, someObject::class);
```

I am running into a type error, as `referencingNames` is obviously a `string`.

What I then tried was to set `$referencingNames` private and use the magic function [`__set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) as it says in the php docs the following

> is run when writing data to inaccessible (protected or private) or non-existing properties

```php
class someObject {
  public int $id;
  private string $referencingNames;

  public ?array $refNamesList;

  public function __set($name, $value) 
  {
    if($name == "referencingNames") {
        $this->referencingNames = $value;
        $this->refNamesList = explode(",", $value);
    } else {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
  } 
}
```

The bad news: this didn't work out. I get back an object where refNamesList stays null. Logging the call of `__set()` did not give me any output, so I assume, it does not get called.

Has anybody an Idea how I can map `GROUP_CONCAT` to an array with PDOs `fetchAll()` without building my own solution?
I mean, fetching all, and iterating the whole thing is still an option, but I was wondering if I can do this more elegantly anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name of the column you are loading is part of the class, it's setting that value anyway without having to call the `__set` method.  So one way (seems to work) is to add a column alias which doesn't exist in the class - nameList in this example...

```
$query = "Select a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) AS nameList 
             FROM a 
             JOIN b on (a.id = b.id_a)"
```

this should then call the `__set` method and you can process when you get nameList...

```
class someObject {
  public int $id;
  public array $referencingNames;

  public function __set($name, $value)
  {
    if($name == "nameList") {
        $this->referencingNames = explode(",", $value);
    } else {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So the php doc is wrong here? As set seems not to be called for the private property?

Comment: @helle, the use of FETCH_CLASS seems to bypass the access modifier.  This makes sense when most classes would use private data and want FETCH_CLASS to still be able to populate them properly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try it out later and accept the answer. Great to have a solution

Comment: Nice !! This worked really good and saves me now lots of time!